# Trying to create a new form helper to add a class onto a text field, but it doesn't seem to be adding that class on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, helper

Here's the helper:

```
module FormHelper
  def phone_number_tag *args
    args.each do |e|
      if e.is_a? Hash and e.has_key? :class
        e[:class] = e[:class] + " phone_number"
      elsif e.is_a? Hash
        e[:class] = "phone_number"
      end
    end
    text_field_tag args
  end
end
```

Now what's weird is that when I throw a debugger in there like so ...

```
module FormHelper
  def phone_number_tag *args
    args.each do |e|
      if e.is_a? Hash and e.has_key? :class
        e[:class] = e[:class] + " phone_number"
      elsif e.is_a? Hash
        e[:class] = "phone_number"
      end
    end
    debugger
    text_field_tag args
  end
end
```

... and run `text_field_tags args` in the console once it hits that debugger, I get:

```
"<input id=\"_:first___:class___input_span2_phone_number___:placeholder___First__\" name=\"first {:class=&gt;&quot;input span2 phone_number&quot;, :placeholder=&gt;&quot;First&quot;}\" type=\"text\" />"
```

However, the HTML output on the rendered page is:

```
<input class="input span2" id="follow_up_phone" name="referral[follow_ups_attributes][0][phone]" size="30" type="text">
```

There's no phone_number class even though in the debugger there was.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What happens if you use "phone-number" as class?

Comment: @SG86 Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be like this:

```
text_field_tag *args
```

(with asterisk *)